# Segue to Tab in navigation controller going to wrong tab, Swift, Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I am clicking a button and pushing to a TabBar Controller.

When I click the button it goes to the first tab only, no matter what number I put in the prepare for segue area.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        let barViewControllers = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
            let nav = barViewControllers.viewControllers![2] as! UINavigationController
        let destinationViewController = nav.topViewController! as UIViewController
    }
```

The one it should go to is the one with the brown background (Number 2, Third Tab)

[Tab controller Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQWRJ.png)

[Iphone App Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwdEH.png)

Comment: Your current code does nothing, you just cast variables and don't use them. This is "prepare", not "show", the decision on showing the next view controller has already been made.

Comment: Ah ok I get it, So I am declaring the controller I want to send the data to but not actually pushing to that controller. I do have more code that sets the data in the controller but I created this in a new program to test it wasn't my current one. I do set data to send normally. so I need to figure out how to push to the 3rd controller in the tab bar controller, am I best doing it from the tab bar controller? when it arrives maybe have a var that that if true it will push to that controller?